# How to help my 3.5-year-old daughter who's suddenly much more attached to me and cries for everything?

Tags: pre-schooler, crying, attachment

My 3.5-year-old daughter has suddenly become more attached to me. She also is crying for everything. Recently, she has gone on a trip with her grandmother 1.5 months back and she used to cry there and missed me a lot. After coming back from there she wants me everytime to be with her. She used to be a very happy child and dance  alot. These days she is the exact opposite.

**How to handle my 3.5-year-old suddenly having become more attached to me?**

Comment: How long was she separated from you? ow did you keep in contact (phone/Skype/etc.)?

Comment: for 10 days.. yes I used to do video call at times but on call everytime she used to cry so used to try to talk audio only.. I never thought she would miss me so much..